# Error Message When Trying To Insert A Record Into A Database

Tags: c#, sql-server

Here is the code:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //1). Declare connection string

            string connectionString = "Data Source = LAPTOP - C5FEB2D0\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog = Upskilling;Integrated Security = True;MultipleActiveResultsSets = True;";

            //2). Write to Student table

            // Make use of the PopulateStudentTable method declared in Line 29 & "connectionString" as the argument

            PopulateStudentTable(connectionString); 

        }

        //3). This is outside the main method. 
        //    Declare specific method and argument to be used in populating said table (Student table)
        static void PopulateStudentTable(string connectionString)
        {
            //3a). Insert 1 record into the Student table
            string query = @"Insert Into [dbo].[Student](FirstName, LastName, City)
            Values('Dan, 'Smith', 'London')";

            //3b). Now, Connect to the SQL Server database 
            //3c). Use the Dependency - "Using System.Data.SqlClient;"
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {

            //3d). Reference the "connection" decalred in Line 34 - for it to open the database.
            //     Use the Open()

                connection.Open();

           //3e). Execute the command using a method that takes 2 parameters - "query" and "connection string"
           //     "query" & "connection" string were declared in Line 29 & 34 respectively.

                using(SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection))
                {

           //3f). Use the command - "command" & the method - "ExecuteNonQuery()"

                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();

                }

            }

        }


    }
}
```

The Error Message I get is:

> Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: Keyword not supported:
>   'multipleactiveresultssets'.    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions.ParseInternal(Hashtable
>   parsetable, String connectionString, Boolean buildChain, Hashtable
>   synonyms, Boolean firstKey)    at
>   System.Data.Common.DbConnectionOptions..ctor(String connectionString,
>   Hashtable synonyms, Boolean useOdbcRules)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionString..ctor(String
>   connectionString)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnectionOptions(String
>   connectionString, DbConnectionOptions previous)    at
>   System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnectionPoolGroup(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key, DbConnectionPoolGroupOptions poolOptions, DbConnectionOptions&
>   userConnectionOptions)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.ConnectionString_Set(DbConnectionPoolKey
>   key)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.set_ConnectionString(String value)
>   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString,
>   SqlCredential credential)    at
>   System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection..ctor(String connectionString)
>   at
>   Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S.Program.PopulateStudentTable(String
>   connectionString) in
>   C:\Users\opeye\Documents\TESTING\UPSKILLING\UPSKILLING
>   PROJECTS\Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S\Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S\Program.cs:line
>   37    at Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S.Program.Main(String[]
>   args) in C:\Users\opeye\Documents\TESTING\UPSKILLING\UPSKILLING
>   PROJECTS\Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S\Writing_Data_To_SQL_Database_From_V_S\Program.cs:line
>   23 Press any key to continue . . .

I have not been able to get a solution so far.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your sample code seems to be missing some using statements. Also, you have too many `s` characters - `MultipleActiveResultsSets` != `MultipleActiveResultSets`.

Comment: You don't seem to using multiple result, so i suggest to remove `MultipleActiveResultsSets = True;`

Comment: FYI Visual Studio is an IDE. It doesn't actually execute your code, nor is it C# or the .NET Framework. The `[visual-studio]` tag is only intended for questions about Visual Studio and not code you write with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mistyped "MultipleActiveResultsSets". The "Result" in it is not plural.

Correct way: "MultipleActiveResultSets".